# Woocommerce Disable Email for Account Creation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to delay/disable the default email sending of New Account on my Woocommerce site.

Right now I can already fire the trigger for email sending when I want it to (after the Thank You page), but I wanna disable the default one because it's duplicated.

Can't use the WC Settings because then that would disable my custom trigger too.

So far this is what I have but it's not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'disable_account_creation_email' );

function disable_account_creation_email( $email_class ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account'], 'trigger' ) );
}
```

I based it off of [the guide here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/unhookremove-woocommerce-emails/) and still trying to play around with it. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about what you want to do but you can go to the WooCommerce settings in the "e-mails" section and disable it.

Comment: That also disables the custom trigger I have on the Thank You page though, that's why I can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your code with follows -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'disable_account_creation_email' );

function disable_account_creation_email( $email_class ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer_notification', array( $email_class, 'customer_new_account' ), 10, 3 );
}
```